# Python If parameter is an object of this class then

Tags: function, class, object, parameters

```py
class x():
    #Something

var1 = 1
var2 = x()

def function(parameter):
    if parameter == #object of x:
        var1 = 2
        return var1

print(function(var2)
```

Output = None

I cant find a way to make this work. Ive tried the inspect module and the isinstance function but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to make a condition where "If this parameter is an object from this specific class then do something"